# How to change Contact form 7 validation message text?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I've a CF7 form and would like to changes the default validation error message(One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.) to custom one.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is in the manual. https://contactform7.com/admin-screen/

Answer (score 0):

there is a setting in the contact form for changing the texts for these error messages.